# Can not connect to wireless network in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, 23.10

I’m using Ubuntu
When I trying to connect to any wireless network through GUI, when I hit on Wi-Fi name nothing happens

So i tried to connect using terminal it doesn’t work too it show me this err message:

```
Error: Failed to add/activate new connection: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

Note : it was working good before but I don’t know why did that happen?

Comment: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.